# Error on posting basic job from JobDiva to LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

In the case of basic application testing, I attempted to test it, but unfortunately, I encountered an error:

X-LI-UUID   :     AAYTcwf4zaC2sjyCod2jWA==

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSsj6.png) The response error is shown in the image

Please advise why is this error happening and what could be done

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "companyApplyUrl": https://www.jobssos.com/candidates/myjobs/openjob_outside.jsp?a=pajdnw688je4ganlett5etqxn9gmns0001xwui48z1lgu23vfi9aos51ybjxndd9&SearchString=&StatesString=&source=linkedin.com&id=2377631&compid=-1,
            "externalJobPostingId": "574-30-02408",
            "jobPostingOperationType": "CREATE",
            "title": "Business Analyst TEST",
            "description": "<div>  <span style=\"font-family: verdana\">  <span style=\"font-size: 12px\">   aaaaa JOB, PLEASE DO NOT APPLY<br />  using data modelling techniques to identify ways in which an organisation can operate more effectively.<br />  communicate with senior people in organisations to find out what they hope to achieve<br />  formulate ways for businesses to improve, based on previous research<br />  persuade internal and external stakeholders of the benefits of new technology or strategies<br />  oversee the implementation of new technology and systems<br />  run workshops and training sessions<br />  exploring how the organisation is currently operating via research, which could include interviewing employees and collecting quantitative data<br />  explore different solutions, their risks, benefits and impacts<br />  proposing solutions to an organisation's leaders, and keeping them updated with progress<br />  creating documents to outline the proposed changes and the steps involved.<br />  ensuring the changes are made – for example, by overseeing the implementation of new technology or a new approach<br />  contributing to training and support for people affected by new systems and processes.</span>  </span>  <br />   </div>  ",
            "listedAt": 1681231943000,
            "location": "Chicago, Illinois, US",
            "companyJobCode": "30-02408",
            "workplaceTypes": [
                "Hybrid"
            ],
            "employmentStatus": "OTHER",
            "experienceLevel": "ENTRY_LEVEL",
            "companyPageUrl": https://www.linkedin.com/company/testing-company-job-posting-407,
            "listingType": "BASIC",
            "availability" : "PUBLIC"
        }
    ]
}

Response – error 
{
    "status": 403,
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Unpermitted fields present in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/elements]"
}
```